# How to change default site in multisite

Tags: wordpress

I tried below changes in config file in wordpress

```
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 2 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 2);
```

Bu its not working

Or any plugin to change default site

Answer (score 0):

You can consider [buddybpress](https://codex.buddypress.org/buddypress-components-and-features/)
go through the link on **WordPress Blogs** section you can notice, It can be used for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

In most cases you may/will need to update a entry in your WP-Config.php file. The code I would recommend taking a look at is the code snippet here:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );
$base = '/';
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mycurrentsite-example.com' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

On the line that has “define(‘DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE’,’mycurrentsite-example.com’);”
You will replace “mycurrentsite-example.com” with your domain. So for example:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
define( 'MULTISITE', true );
define( 'SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true );
$base = '/';
define( 'DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mysite.com' );
define( 'PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/' );
define( 'SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
define( 'BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

For hosting in WordPress, there's a setting in UI:

> Profile (icon at top right) > Account Settings > Primary Site

Not sure if it's there for third party hosting or self hosting though.